# Add alpha channel to a given color

Tags: css

I have a couple of  next to each other that I want to style with CSS. I want to apply a wide variety of colors for the background, but I want the lower one to be the same color with reduced opacity, so I thought of this:

```
span.foo{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1); /*or whatever*/
    color:white;
}

span.foo:last-child{
    background-color: rgba(*,*,*,0.5); /*just an example*/
}
```

So I want to change the opacity of the already defined background without affecting the opacity of the text just by using CSS3.

Is this possible?

Comment: Hi, you could try this with filters, check this link https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/

Comment: For a small number of colors, it might be fastest to use a tool like the [HTML Color Picker](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp) to convert it for you. Paste in your hex color, for example **#23a** and it will give you **rgb(34, 51, 170)**, so just add the alpha amount you want, like **rgba(34, 51, 170, 0.2)** (where 0 is transparent and 1 is opaque). But I agree that it would be nice if alpha could be added to a hex color with CSS alone, without needing to reformat to RGB.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe there is no way to do it.

Css is very limited by itself, and there isn't much you can do with it.

The only way you could add opacity is:

```
opacity: 0.5
```

But the above would also affect the text itself, not only background.

However, you could wrap it in way that would separate the background blocks from the text, so that would keep the color of the text untouched.

**EDIT:** See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YfSn7/30/

But that may look somewhat ridiculous, so I wouldn't much advice using it.

Guess you would have to accept that this is impossible, if you do actually want to make things simpler instead of over-complicating them.

Answer (score 20):

If you want to use modern CSS:

```
--color_rgb: 0, 0, 0;
background-color: rgba(var(--color_rgb), 0.5);
```

But it's still not possible to add alpha to a *given* color, as in "some other style sheet applied this color in RGB, Hex or something else".

Answer (score 15):

If you have Sass:

```
background-color: rgba(white, 0.5);
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use CSS variables:

```css
span.foo {
    --background-color: 0, 0, 0;
    background-color: rgba(var(--background-color), 1);
    color: white;
}

span.foo:last-child {
    background-color: rgba(var(--background-color), 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It can be done using JavaScript as follows:

```
function adjustHexOpacity(color, opacity) {
  const r = parseInt(color.slice(1, 3), 16);
  const g = parseInt(color.slice(3, 5), 16);
  const b = parseInt(color.slice(5, 7), 16);

  return 'rgba(' + r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ', ' + opacity + ')';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any way of doing this, the excessive repeating of values is one of the failings of CSS.

So if your standard color is `rgba(0,0,0,1);` then you'll need `rgba(0,0,0,0.5);` as the transparent version.

You could perhaps do something like this client-side with a bit of javascript, but that's not exactly clean.

Answer (score 2):

As other answers have mentioned, we can make use of custom properties and the alpha channel of a supporting color function. For example:

```
:root {
  --color: 255 255 255;
}
span.foo {
  background-color: rgba(0 0 0 / 1); /*or whatever*/
  color: rgb(var(--color));
}

span.foo:last-child {
  color: rgb(var(--color) / 0.5); /*just an example*/
}
```

```css
:root {
  --color: 255 255 255;
}

span.foo {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  /*or whatever*/
  color: rgb(var(--color));
}

span.foo:last-child {
  color: rgb(var(--color) / 0.5);
  /*just an example*/
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="foo">First child</span>
  <span class="foo">Last child</span>
</div>
```

However, the limitation with the above approach is that you can’t convert a custom property’s color value from one type to another:

```
:root {
  --color: #ffffff; /* HEX Color */
}
span.foo {
  background-color: rgba(0 0 0 / 1); /*or whatever*/
  color: rgb(var(--color)); /* doesn't work */
}

span.foo:last-child {
  color: rgb(var(--color) / 0.5); /* you can't convert a hex color to a rgb color */
}
```

This is now possible with the Level 5 CSS-Color spec:

## [Relative Color Syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-5/#relative-colors)

The basic idea is that given an original color - which can be defined in any [color type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value) notation: hex, rgb, hsl etc or even *named colors*!! (like 'gold') - we can use various functions such as hsl(), rgb() , lch() to transform the original color into a relative color by changing one or more of the color's components / color channels.

So let's say we started with the color 'tomato'

Now I want to add an alpha of 0.5 to that color

We could use the `rgb()` function as follows:

```
color: rgb(from tomato r g b / .5);
```

So the rgb() function converts the color 'tomato' to the rgb color type and lets us change any of its `r-g-b-a` channels!!

```css
.wpr {
  --color: tomato
}
.original {
  color: var(--color)
}
.relative {
  color: rgb(from tomato r g b / .5);
}

.wpr div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  background-color: wheat;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 1rem
}
```

```html
<div class="wpr">
  <div class="original">original</div>
  <div class="relative">relative</div>
</div>
```

If we just wanted to **decrease** the alpha by say 20% we could use calc():

```
color: rgb(from tomato r g b / calc(alpha - 0.2))
```

```css
.wpr {
  --color: tomato
}
.original {
  color: var(--color)
}
.relative {
  color: rgb(from tomato r g b / calc(alpha - 0.2));
}

.wpr div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  background-color: wheat;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 1rem
}
```

```html
<div class="wpr">
  <div class="original">original</div>
  <div class="relative">relative</div>
</div>
```

Another example:

Let's say we want to convert our original named-color to hsl and update it's hue to find complemetary colors:

```
hsl(from var(--color) calc(h + 60) s l);
```

```css
.wpr {
  --color: wheat;
}
.original {
  background-color: var(--color)
}
.hue60 {
  background-color: hsl(from var(--color) calc(h + 60) s l);
}
.hue120 {
  background-color: hsl(from var(--color) calc(h + 120) s l);
}
.hue180 {
  background-color: hsl(from var(--color) calc(h + 180) s l);
}
.hue240 {
  background-color: hsl(from var(--color) calc(h + 240) s l);
}

.wpr div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 1rem
}
```

```html
<div class="wpr">
  <div class="original">original</div>
  <div class="hue60">relative</div>
  <div class="hue120">relative</div>
  <div class="hue180">relative</div>
  <div class="hue240">relative</div>
</div>
```